# ¿Por qué se retorna un 0 un void?

Tags: c

No entiendo porque se retorna un 0 en el main.

```
void main(){
   return 0;
}
```

Es un pequeño ejemplo, es que me he encontrado varias veces con que en el main se devulve un 0 y a veces no. Y no entiendo porque se devuelve algo al ser una función de tipo void. Tambien lo que no entiendo muy bien es cuando usar el return EXIT_SUCCESS y el EXIT_FAILURE, se que generan mensajes de error.
Y no sabría implementar un boolean en c, se que este tipo de variable no existe.

Comment: Tal vez esto responda a tu pregunta [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Answer (score 0):

**No entiendo porque se retorna un 0 en el main.**

Si revisamos uno de los [borradores del estándar C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf), encontramos lo siguiente (traducción mia):

> **5.1.2.2.1 Inicio del programa**
>
> 1) La función llamada al inicio del programa se llama `main`. Esta función no requiere de declaración previa. Debe definirse con un tipo de retorno `int` y sin parámetros`:
>
> `int main(void){ /* ... */ }`
>
> o con dos parámetros (nos referiremos a ellos como `argc` y `argv` aunque se pueden usar cualquier otro nombre ya que son variables locales de la función en que se declaran):
>
> `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ /* ... */ }`
>
> o equivalente.

Es decir, que la función `main` **no debería implementarse** usando `void` como tipo de retorno.

O, dicho de otra forma, una vez uses `void` como tipo de retorno para `main`, lo que suceda después (tanto si funciona como si no) es irrelevante.

**no entiendo muy bien es cuando usar el return EXIT_SUCCESS y el EXIT_FAILURE**

Tanto `EXIT_SUCCESS` como `EXIT_FAILURE` son sendas **macros**.

- `EXIT_SUCCESS` se debería usar cuando tu programa finaliza correctamente **sin errores**. El valor típico de esta macro es `0`.
- `EXIT_FAILURE` se usa para indicar que el programa ha finalizado con un error genérico.

Así mismo es posible generar códigos de error específicos usando cualquier valor diferente a los dados por estas dos macros:

```
int main(void)
{
  return 7; // Codigo de error 7
}
```

El significado de los diferentes códigos de error debería estar documentado en la ayuda de tu programa.

Ahora bien, que tu programa devuelva un código de error no implica que alguien tenga que escuchar o atenderlo. Los códigos de error se usan sobretodo al programar scripts (`sh`, `bat`, ...) y cuando una aplicación ejecuta otra en segundo plano. En estos casos se suele verificar el código de retorno de la aplicación para saber si la misma ha finalizado satisfactoriamente.

**se que generan mensajes de error**

Como has visto, esta afirmación es totalmente falsa. Solo sirven para indicar si el programa ha finalizado o no correctamente... pero no se genera mensaje alguno. Para que aparezca un mensaje de error es necesario que otro programa o script recoja el código devuelto por la aplicación y genere un mensaje acorde a dicho código.

**Y no sabría implementar un boolean en c**

En C no existe el tipo booleano como tal. Sin embargo se utiliza `int` como sustituto barato con las siguientes condiciones:

- `0`: representa el estado FALSO
- cualquier otro valor: representa el estado VERDADERO. En el caso de evaluaciones booleanas, el valor devuelto será 1.

Esto se puede verificar facilmente:

```
int numero = 10;
int flag = numero > 5;
printf("%d", flag); // Imprime 1
```

Y es por esta razón que los resultados de las evaluaciones booleanas en C se pueden usar en operaciones aritméticas:

```
int pares = 0;
for( int i=0; i<6; i++ )
{
  pares += ((i % 2) == 0);
}
printf("%d", pares); // Imprime 3
```

Ahora bien, por comodidad y legibilidad, podemos usar la cabecera `stdbool.h` (C99 en adelante) la cual nos provee de el tipo `bool` (como un alias de `int`), y las constantes `true` y `false` (sendos defines cuyos valores son 1 y 0):

```
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
  bool flag = 20 > 5;
  if( flag == true )
    printf("20 es mayor que 5");
  else
    printf("20 no es mayor que 5");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Según tengo entendido el return 0; le esta indicando que ahi termino tu codigo, pero no se mucho sobre eso. Pero para implementar booleanos en C simplemente tenes que implimentar la librería de booleanos con #include